# Android play url redirect / ask them to login e.g. for Internal Testing invites

Tags: android, google-play

So you have an internal test for Google Play app.
You want to send all your emails you invite to the test a link to install your app.

But some may not be logged in to play store on their PC.

Found a way to send them a login link that redirects.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Url encode your store app
https://www.urlencoder.org/

Concat it to the end of this for the continue parameter.

https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?passive=1209600&continue=

Then when you email people your app e.g. internal testers, they will be prompted to login then redirected to the app page to install it or if already logged in they will be redirected to the app page to install it.